# Making a checkpoint of SQLITE database in WAL mode after each insert/update/delete operation

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, wal

I have SQLITE database inside my Xamarin Android app and I need to be able to read and write from it concurrently from different threads and/or processes. So I'm trying now to use it in WAL mode. It works fine mostly. SQLITE_BUSY errors which I experienced before not occur anymore.

The problem is that I also would like to be able to take this database off the device (i.e., send by email) - preferably, in one file.

In WAL mode I have the main database file x.db3 along with x.db3-wal and x.db3-shm,  which is not good enough for this purpose. 
Theerefore y idea was to execute `pragma checkpoint(passive)` after each insert, update or delete operation so the database will actually almost always consist from one file. Updates are rare in my case, so performance hit is probably not an issue. I understand that during checkpoint the readers will not be able to read the data and I can handle it.
But anyway my intuition tells me that this is not a right way to use WAL logging and that's why I'm asking. It "looks" to me like abuse.

I'd appreciate any ideas about problems I may run into with this approach.

Comment: You should use the [backup API](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) to copy an open, in-use sqlite database  (assuming the interface library for the language that you're using supports it, of course. Many omit much of the C api).

Comment: Why not add a feature/action in the app that performs the `pragma checkpoint`, closing of any open connections, and then creates an email, adds the db attachment, sends, etc... and then re-opens the DB connection

Comment: @SushiHangover some of the connections are from services and broadcast receivers, so it's not easy to close them all. I can of course make a checkpoint before sending, but I thought it would be better to get rid of additional files as soon as possible.

Comment: And by the way, why do I need to close any connections before copying the database? As long as they are only readers and do not write to the database while I am sending it, I don't see any problem to leave them opened. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Grisha Assuming you are holding a read-lock on the database while copying the physical file there should not be any problem. (Personally I structure secondary connections (read-only or not) to close after X amount of non-use time and have the connection auto-open the db as it frees up file handles, memory, etc... but that is a story for a different time about mem-leaks, Mono cross-peer GC issues, etc..)